# File not found in bundle

Tags: swift, xcode

I've just submitted my app for review on the store and got some Crashlytics reports with this error:

> Fatal error: Failed to locate CountryNumbers.json in bundle.

During local runs, with debug and release (and with simulator and real device), the app works as it should. I've checked the copy bundle resources and the file is there.

I read the file during a static initialisation of a variable

```swift
static let allCountries: [CPData] = Bundle.main.decode("CountryNumbers.json")
```

and the decode extension code

```swift
extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }
     .....
```

Does anyone know if I missed a config or why this is happening?

EDIT:
Ok, so the solution was to move the json file up a level so it won't be in `Assets/` folder but in root

I'd very much appreciated if someone can explain why.

[image: copy bundle resources]

[image]

Comment: Is Assets a folder reference?

Comment: @matt no, it's not not a reference, it's a standalone folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assets and preview assets are the same thing used for different purpose. Preview assets does not get archived when app is sent because content inside are meant to be used in Xcode for development only. Maybe you’ve put your file to the preview assets or that your assets folder has the same settings as preview assets for some reason.

Comment: Not sure how to check what you said